# I was given a Warning when creating bins using .loc

Tags: python, pandas, binning

I tried to use .loc to create different bins.

```
df.loc[df['age'] < 20, 'age'] = 1
df.loc[(df['age'] >= 20) & (df['age'] < 40), 'age'] = 2
df.loc[(df['age'] >= 40) & (df['age'] < 60), 'age'] = 3
df.loc[(df['age'] >= 60) & (df['age'] < 80), 'age'] = 4
df.loc[ df['age'] >= 80, 'age'] = 5

df['age'] = df['age'].astype(int)
```

It was successful, but I received the warning:

/Users/john/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1765: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
isetter(loc, value)

What did I do wrong or should do better so it doesnt come up? Can I still use .loc method?

Thank you!

Comment: Because your data frame `df` is a slice from another dataframe.

Comment: I did a df = df.dropna() before to drop null values. Is that the problem?

Comment: How do you create `df`?

Comment: df = pd.read_csv('churn.csv')
I then want to drop rows with null values under a specific column, then make a prediction model.

Comment: I used df.dropna(subset = ["risk_type"], inplace=True), so it is solved. However, I am thinking what triggered it when other examples do not.